# Localness of the UFD Property

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

If $A$ is a noetherian domain and $A_p$ is a UFD for some prime ideal, is there some $f$ not contained in $p$ such that $A_f$ is a UFD?

Comment: The answer is no. But the proof I know needs some background in algebraic geometry (Jacobian of a projective smooth curve).

Comment: I wanted to use this as a lemma for an algebraic geometry problem anyway, so I would be more than happy with an algebraic geometry disproof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no in general.

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve over some field $K$, of positive genus. Let $U$ be a non-empty affine open subset of $C$ and let $A=\mathcal O_C(U)$. Then $A$ is a Dedekind domain. In particular, the localization of $A$ at any prime ideal is a PID, hence UFD. Let $V\subseteq U$ be an open subset (e.g. defined as $D(f)$, with $\mathcal O_X(V)=A_f$) and let us see whether $\mathcal O_X(V)$ is UFD, or equivalently, PID, or again $\mathrm{Pic}(V)=\{ 1\}$ (the Picard group of $V$ is the same as the class ideal group of $\mathcal O_X(V)$).

Let $p_1,\dots, p_n$ be the points in the complement of $V$ in $C$. Any divisor of degree $0$ on $C$ gives rise, by restriction, to a divisor on $V$. Moreover, this restriction is compatible with linear equivalence. So we have a canonical map 
$$ \mathrm{Pic}^0(C)\to \mathrm{Pic}(V).$$
**Edit** (thanks to Georges' comments) The elements of the kernel of this map are all linear combinations of the classes of $p_1, \dots, p_n$: if a divisor $D$ on $C$ is trivial on $V$, then $D\sim \sum_i a_ip_i$ with $a_i\in \mathbb Z$. Therefore we obtain an exact sequence
$$ 0\to H \to \mathrm{Pic}^0(C)\to \mathrm{Pic}(V)$$
with $H$ a finitely generated abelian group. **end of edit.**

If $\mathcal O_C(V)$ has trivial Picard group, then $\mathrm{ Pic}^0(C)$ is a finitely generated abelian group. But this is not always true. In fact, if $J$ is the Jacobian of $C$ (and suppose $C$ has a rational point in $K$), then $\mathrm{ Pic}^0(C)=J(K)$. If $K$ is algebraically closed and uncountable, then $J(K)$ is uncountable because $J$ is an algebraic variety of positive dimension (equal to the genus of $C$).

Concrete example: let $C$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb C$ and take $U=C\setminus \{ 0\}$. Then for all $f\in A:=\mathcal O_C(U)$, $A_f$ is never a PID.

Comment: +1: the mathematics is very nice and the writing perfect.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Thanks ! I think the example with elliptic curves is also in one of your posts, but I was unable to find it.

Comment: Dear Cantlog: yes, I knew the example with an elliptic curve but hadn't realized that it generalises to higher genus: thanks for teaching me! By the way, I'm puzzled by your invocation of $Pic^0(C)$: is there a canonical map $\mathbb Z^n\to Pic^0(C)$ ? As far as I can judge the relevant exact sequence in general is $\mathbb Z^n\to Pic(C)\to Pic(V) \to 0$.  I see no use for $Pic^0(C)$. Am I missing something?